# Trying to make my new characters go back into a single string

Tags: python

```
key=7
file=open('enprac.txt','r')
for line in file:
    words=line.split()
    for char in words:
        for letter in char:
            number=ord(letter)
            newnumber=number^key
            newletter=chr(newnumber)
            print(newletter)
file.close()

file2=open('decrypt.txt','w')
file2.write(newletter)
file2.close()
```

I am trying to take a message from a file encrypt with xor and the send the encrypted message to the next file for decrypting. The problem im having is that I have the encrypted message just that it is only printing the last letter to the file. How do you make it so the encrypted characters turn into a string that would then send the whole encrypted message to the file.

Comment: First create an empty string at the beginning, then as you create new letters, add them to the string. Write that entire string to `file2` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You are never actually constructing a string with your new letters to add to the file. You are also not looping over the lines in the file correctly. Try something like:

```py
encrypted = ""
key = 7
file = open('enprac.txt', 'r')

for line in file.readlines():
    words = line.split()

    for char in words:
        for letter in char:
            number = ord(letter)
            newnumber = number ^ key
            newletter = chr(newnumber)
            encrypted += newletter

file.close()

file2 = open('decrypt.txt', 'w')
file2.write(encrypted)
file2.close()
```